# With scope based repository workpsace will all the members be able to check in the code.?

Tags: rtc

With scope based repository workpsace will all the members be able to check in the code.?

Or only deliver to the stream is possible like public repository work space.

Answer (score 0):

> With scope based repository workpsace will all the members be able to check in the code.?

No: only the owner of a repo workspace can check in code, or accept change set from other flow targets.

> Or only deliver to the stream is possible like public repository work space.

No: only the owner of a repo workspace can initiate a deliver.
If you want to deliver change set from another repo workspace, you have to accept them in your own repo workspace first (by modifying its flow target in order to temporarily point to that other repo workspace), and then, once accepted, you can deliver them to the stream.

Comment: So users can get the code updates from the scoped workspace and make some updates and deliver it to the corresponding stream via the private workspace. Is my understanding correct.?

Comment: Yes, that is the idea.

Comment: I have another scenario 

If code is delivered to a stream will it have any impact on another stream which has the same component.

eg : stream 1 Comp 1 - baseline 1

Stream 2 Comp 1- baseline 1

If a create a repo workpace out of stream 2 and make code changes and deliver to Stream 2 will the change be available in stream 1.

Are the components same or two different copies?

Comment: @user3302323 the components are the same on both stream, but each one will display only the latest baseline delivered to their Stream: ie: the deliver to Stream2 will have no impact on the same component in stream1: its state in Stream1 remains untouched.

Comment: so from the trunk stream 1 i create another stream 2. Changes in Stream 2 with checkins wont have impact on stream 1. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Thanks for the answer, The confusion happened because both the streams will have same component.

Comment: @user3302323 no problem: having the same component on different streams is a common practice: each streams represents a development effort: for instance a stream 'dev', and a stream '1.0' (for the release, where you deliver hotfix change sets)

Comment: One more clarification on using scoped repository , if we use scoped repository and private repository we need to switch between the flow target every time and take updates, is it not effficient to use private repository for each user and directly taking update from stream.

Comment: @user3302323 as I mentioned before, I prefer always creating scope-repo only, not private repo. But yes, each user has his/her own repo workspace (scoped, to be visible by the rest of the team), and the default flow target is the common stream.

Comment: then we need always the same code in both scope and private repo. Is it not a overhead?

Comment: @user3302323 not if don't create any private repo workspace ;)

Comment: You have said that code delivery is possible only from private repo. Then how can all the members use the scope workpsace

Comment: @user3302323 I said "only the owner of a repo workspace can initiate a deliver." I did not mention the nature of that repo workspace: it can be private or scoped.

Comment: So only the owner of the repo workspace can checkin or deliver the changes ? Is it correct?

Comment: @user3302323 Yes. The idea is for an owner to not have the surprise, when coming in the morning, to discover his/her own repo workspace with new checkins or having done new deliver without his/her knowledge.

Comment: So in my view i feel Private repo is better and sync can be done using code from code ? Am i wrong ?

Comment: So in my view i feel Private repo is better and sync can be done using code from Stream? Am i wrong ?

Comment: @user3302323 no need for private repo: a scoped-repo is enough as it allows your colleagues to get back your committed change set from your scoped repo workspace and publish them for you (from their own repo workspace). If your repo workspace is private and you are not available for any reason... your committed change set are stuck and not visible from anyone. That is bad.

Comment: I am in team with 10 developers. So i have to change the flow target 9 times to get the checked in code from others. (If i have to be in Sync). So i think it is a overhead.

Comment: @user3302323 I agree: the natural flow is to deliver to the stream, or to accept change set from the stream (only *one* source). You change that flow target to a colleague repo workspace only if you need it (ie, not every morning, but in the rare occurrence when that colleague has committed some interesting change set but has not deliver them to the stream yet). The rest of the time, you sync your own (scoped) repo workspace only from the Stream.